# asp image doesn't display at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have this simple asp.net page that have this line that defines an IMG control

> ```
>                <asp:Image src="~/Pics/about.png" ID="about" runat="server" />
> ```

where the correct path for the image file would be :

http://www.khaterah.com/Pics/about.png

but this image doesn't display at all on the local server or on the web server and i don't know why ?!

Comment: have you tried modifying the src path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to be using the `ImageUrl` property. Not `src`

Answer (score 3):

The [asp:Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) control uses the [`ImageUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx) attribute and not `src`

Try this:

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Pics/about.png" ID="about" runat="server" />
```